# Why would running the same query successively on Redis produce faster and faster results?

Tags: redis

I don't believe that redis caches the results of commands, correct? If so, then why would I see the following on my redis server for the same query. For reference, this is redis running in a VM. I checked the smaps file as described in http://redis.io/topics/latency and see no swapping on the OS level (all 0kb in Swap for the process), but is it possible that running redis in a VM pages memory to disk and back? Or... are these results expected due to some kind of redis optimization for commonly run commands?

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[4]> sinterstore testdb ClientId:1637 PublisherId:1
(integer) 240001
(4.46s)
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[4]> sinterstore testdb ClientId:1637 PublisherId:1
(integer) 240001
(3.77s)
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[4]> sinterstore testdb ClientId:1637 PublisherId:1
(integer) 240001
(0.92s)
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[4]> sinterstore testdb ClientId:1637 PublisherId:1
(integer) 240001
(0.64s)
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[4]> sinterstore testdb ClientId:1637 PublisherId:1
(integer) 240001
(0.67s)
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[4]> sinterstore testdb ClientId:1637 PublisherId:1
(integer) 240001
(0.73s)
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[4]> scard ClientId:1637
(integer) 796529
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[4]> scard PublisherId:1
(integer) 311092
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[4]> sinterstore testdb ClientId:1637 PublisherId:1
(integer) 240001
(1.88s)
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[4]> sinterstore testdb ClientId:1637 PublisherId:1
(integer) 240001
(0.69s)
```

Comment: Answers here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/redis-db/-ZH__Zv0upQ

Answer (score 0):

CPU caching! Quite interesting, more reading available [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) (among other places)